# Wordpress custom admin functions security

Tags: admin, security, options

i have a case in my admin panel where i need to call my own function that resides in my own php file, with a GET request. This function is actually removing entries from the database.

So, i would like to make sure that this cannot be invoked from anybody else than the admin user. What is the best way of doing that ? Notice that my 'example.php?filename=..' script is executed directly and should return with refreshing the page on the admin panel.

How do i secure that properly ? Is there a better way of doing that while being controlled by Wordpress default security measures ?

It would be also great to be able to execute things like get_option in the context of my php code.

Answer (score 2):

Read about ["Nonces"](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces).

Create one and append it to your URL:

```
$url = 'example.php?filename=whatever&nonce=' . wp_create_nonce('my_sensitive_action');
```

When your request is fulfilled check for it:

```
// here verify if the nonce was used before
if(wp_verify_nonce($_GET['nonce'], 'my_sensitive_action')){
  // it's ok, it wasn't used before
}
```

Also the validity of these nonces has a time limit, like one day or so.
If the nonce is not used within this period, it will expire...

Comment: yes, i know about nonces, but these are mainly used for csrf types of attacks. An admin check should still happen to avoid privilege escalations. I was thinking of maybe somehow including my code in a more proper way. I was reading a few things just now about wordpress custom actions. It feels like this is the way to go, probably along with an is_admin() check, do you think that's correct ? +1 for your answer, thanx !

Comment: well, you can always do extra checks, see [current_user_can](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) for example. is_admin() is probably not necessary, as you most likely hooked your function to an action available only within the administration pages, right?